# Correct co-domain for the discrete Heaviside (unit) step function? $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb R$ or $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \{0,1\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form)

> Discrete form:
> An alternative form of the unit step, defined instead as a function $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (i.e. taking in a discrete variable $n$), is:
> \begin{align}
> H[n]=
> \begin{cases}
> 0, \quad n<0\\
> 1, \quad n\geq 0
> \end{cases}
> \tag 1
> \end{align}
> or using the half-maximum convention:
> \begin{align}
> H[n]=
> \begin{cases}
> 0, \quad n<0\\
> \frac{1}{2}, \quad n=0\\
> 1, \quad n> 0
> \end{cases}
> \tag 2
> \end{align}
> where $n$ is an integer.

My questions:

Is it not wrong to use the co-domain $\mathbb R$ in $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

I.e. the definition in $(1)$: is it not more correct to write $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \{0,1\}$?

And the definition in $(2)$:  is it not more correct to write $H:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \{0,\frac{1}{2},1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

When you have $f:A\to B$ then $B$ is not necessarily $f(A)$ the image of $A$, we just have the inclusion $f(A)\subset B$.

In the case $B=f(A)$ we call $B$ the image or the range.

For instance you define $\sin:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and do not bother that image is in fact $[-1,1]$.

Maybe what is bothering you is that $H$ domain is $\mathbb N$ and expect somehow codomain to be same?

Anyway it is not an issue, I mean none is wrong, only one is more precise ($\{0,\frac 12,1\}$) than the other ($\mathbb R$).